# Issue with Amazon Transcibe

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-connect

I have a few recording files (audio files from Amazon connect .wav format) is stored in the S3 bucket.
I followed this link (https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-audio-transcript-transcribe/) to convert the audio files to Transcript using Amazon Transcribe.

It is successfully converted to Transcript.

**NOTE**: the voice in the audio files are very clear but the only thing is it was there in the decent Indian accent (Not in UK / US accent)

Surprisingly, **It is not able to detect many words correctly.** Most of the words were wrong

1) Is there a setting, I need to configure for detecting the Indian accent?
2) Is there anyone tested with US / UK accent and detected at least 80 percent correct?
3) Can anyone suggest What is the other tool anyone prefers for converting the audio to text?

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to transcribe with [Indian English](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/what-is-transcribe.html) with code

> Indian English (en-IN)

Hope it does not start to misbehave for the parts that are in different accents like UK/US. But still worth a try. Otherwise you may need to think about splitting the audio in different parts, which obvioulsy will be cumbersome.

Comment: I checked this already, But where do I need to specify this code? You mean in Amazon Transcribe API, If so could you point me an example - Appreciated

Comment: @Harry depends on what sdk are you using. But here is teh API reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/API_StartTranscriptionJob.html#transcribe-StartTranscriptionJob-request-LanguageCode